# Ubuntu 9.10, login screen error

Tags: ubuntu, login, display

Recently I installed Ubuntu 9.10.. I was trying to install some java runtime, and after the installation was done, I did a reboot.. Ubuntu booted normally but the normal Ubuntu 9.10 login screen is gone..now I have an old Debian style login screen asking for username..
the screen is similar to this one here, but with a black background:

[image]

I thought that it was something with usplash, but in the end I realised that it's something with GDM.. on the Debian login screen, if I press CTRL + ALT + F1, I can get to the terminal and from there I login normally with my username and pass..

After I'm doing "sudo gdm" and it's login automatically to my gnome desktop..after that if I logout, the normal Ubuntu 9.10 login screen is back..

After some rebooting, the old style Debian login screen is back again.

Any ideas what I should do, or what configuration I should change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you accidently overwrite or otherwise break your ~/.gdm file you might an error like this.

You could try something like this (with fingers crossed):

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gdm && sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

Comment: should i do this in gnome enviroment? or logout and enter in terminal mode?

Comment: HEY MAN ! IT WORKED ! ;) thx a lot m8 ;)

Comment: excellent :) glad I could help